# How to make Joomla FaceBook connect to post Wall Entries?

Tags: php, facebook, api, joomla, facebook-wall

I'm trying to make Joomla's JFBConnect post on the user's FB wall some of the user's actions on the website (forum posts, comments, favorites etc.)

Any ideas? API references? Any related Joomla/FB documentation?

Comment: You might want to post your best code attempt.

Comment: I got FB/Joomla to work as far as Connectivity. I'm looking for a lead in the FB API for this sort of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your request with: http://netqcreative.com. They have many tools with facebook:
Qgallerypro - Facebook gallery for joomla, Auto post wall, comment ...